# How to group by a property on a time window in Esper?

Tags: java, esper

Let's say I want to count stock events within a time window. Each event has symbol and timestamp (in seconds) properties. So for a time window of 10 seconds the input (symbol, timestamp):

```
GE, 5
GOOG, 5
GE, 11
GE, 13
```

Should yield (symbol, count, time window):

```
GE, 1, 1
GOOG, 1, 1
GE, 2, 2
```

I tried various ways of achieving this: ext_timed view, injecting an external timing event and joining on that and [disabling the internal timer](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#api-controlling-time) and injecting time events, but so far have had no success.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the external timer. For example:

```
runtime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(5));
runtime.sendEvent(new StockEvent("GE"));
runtime.sendEvent(new StockEvent("GOOG"));

runtime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(11));
runtime.sendEvent(new StockEvent("GE"));
```

The EPL is simply

```
select count(*) from StockEvent.win:time(10) group by symbol
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, didn't work. The output I got was: symbol: GE, count: 1
symbol: GOOG, count: 1
symbol: GE, count: 0
symbol: GE, count: 1
symbol: GE, count: 2

Comment: Your expected output seems off. SInce between "GE, 5" and "GE, 13" only 8 seconds pass (and not more then 10) they are in the same sliding 10-second time window. Tested in the online tool http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/index.html.  t=t.plus(5 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='GE'}
StockTick={symbol='GOOG'}
t=t.plus(6 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(2 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='GE'}

Comment: Oh I think your "window" is an interval that starts at 0 and goes to 10, and then from 10 to 20?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.

Comment: Ok first set the time to zero. Then 'create context Every10Sec start @now end after 10 sec' and 'context Every10Sec select count(*) from MyEvent group by symbol output snapshot when terminated;'. There is no time window needed.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there I think. Just one thing: when I compile the statement with `epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL("create context Every10Sec start @now end after 10 sec; context Every10Sec select count(*) from MyEvent group by symbol output snapshot when terminated")` I get an exception: `Exception in thread "main" com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near ';' ('sec' is a reserved keyword) expecting end-of-input but found a semicolon ';'`. Why is that?